# Invalid JSON format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using JSON.Serialize to generate JSON from Apex class object then sending JSON request to Ruby on RAILS but I'm getting invalid JSON format because SALESFORCE is sending JSON with escape character format.

```
{“{\”enpoint\”:\”\”,\”addresss\”:\”bangalore\”,\”id\”:\”12345\”}"}
```

Please note, I am using JSON.serialize(obj) to generate the JSON string.

```
["{\"Status\":\"Json format is invalid. Please check JSON format\"}"]
```

Comment: You are probably serializing an already serialized Json, are you sure obj, isn't already a Json String? Did you output it in apex? what did you see?

Comment: I'm using below line of code to generate JSON string- JSONGenerator gen=JSON.createGenerator(true);
        return Json.serialize(root) ; Here, root is the object of class.

Comment: I'm using below line of code to generate JSON string- JSONGenerator gen=JSON.createGenerator(true); return Json.serialize(root) ; Here, root is the object of class.

Comment: Please add this code to your question, so we can understand what you are doing. When you are Using the gereator you won't need serialize, you just return it with gen.getAsString(); <- this is already a Json

Comment: Thanks Basti. I don't think we can pass object name in gen.genAsString() method. Also, when we create gen object on JSON then also could not pass object name here. Sorry, I am asking too many thing but I'm very new in Salesforce. ( JSONGenerator gen=JSON.createGenerator(true))

Comment: Example objBody=new Example();
        objBody.id=‘S001’;
        objBody.cookie_id='';
        objBody.name=‘Ramesh’;
        objBody.source=‘Mail’;
       RootObject root=new RootObject();
        root.activity=new Activity();
        root.activity=objBody;
        JSONGenerator gen=JSON.createGenerator(true);
         return gen.getAsString();

Answer (score 1):

With your given object structure you won't need the JSON generator, just use serialize:

```
RootObject root=new RootObject();
root.activity=new Activity();

Example objBody=new Example();
objBody.id='S001';
objBody.cookie_id='';
objBody.name='Ramesh';
objBody.source='Mail';

root.activity=objBody;

return JSON.serialize(root);
```

Please add the code from the comments to your Question (click "edit" on the question)

Comment: Thanks Basti. I copy your code in my Apex class but still Salesforce is sending JSON request with escape characters to  Ruby On Rails API.

Comment: We are sending JSON request to Rails API which is calling from Salesforce. API is failing because of invalid JSON structure.I tried all Salesforce provide JSON method but still RAILS API is receiving JSON with escape character format.